# Negative correlation between $\hat{\beta}_1$ and $\hat{\beta}_2$

Tags: expected-value, regression, correlation, parameter-estimation

So today I've seen a lecture regarding multiple linear regression with response $y$, an intercept and two explanatory variables $x_1$ and $x_2$. That is,
$$y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1x_{i1}+\beta_2x_{i2}+\epsilon_i$$
We let $\hat{\beta}_0$, $\hat{\beta}_1$ and $\hat{\beta}_2$ be the least square estimators for $\beta_0$,$\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$.

So the lecturer said that we could reflect over the following: If the sample correlation of the two explanatory variables $x_1$ and $x_2$ is positive, i.e. $r_{x_1,x_2}>0$ then the correlation between $\hat{\beta}_1$ and $\hat{\beta}_2$ is negative and I just wonder how I can show it. Any suggestion would be helpful!